# ReadLine and encoding of the extended ascii table

Tags: java, android

Good day.

I have an ASCII file with Spanish words. They contain only characters between A and Z, plus Ñ, ASCII Code 165 (http://www.asciitable.com/).
I get this file with this source code:

```
InputStream is = ctx.getAssets().open(filenames[lang_code][w]);
InputStreamReader reader1 = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(reader1, 8000);

try {
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                 workOn(line);
                 // do a lot of things with line
            }
    reader.close();
    is.close();
} catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

What here I called workOn() is a function that should extract the characters codes from the strings and is something like that:

```
    private static void workOn(String s) {      
    byte b;
    for (int w = 0; w < s.length(); w++) {
        b = (byte)s.charAt(w);
                    // etc etc etc
            }
}
```

Unfortunately what happens here is that I cannot identify b as an ASCII code when it represents the Ñ letter. The value of b is correct for any ascii letter, and returns -3 when dealing with Ñ, that, brought to signed, is 253, or the ASCII character ². Nothing similar to Ñ...

What happens here? How should I get this simple ASCII code?

What is getting me mad is that I cannot find a correct coding. Even, if I go and browse the UTF-8 table (http://www.utf8-chartable.de/) Ñ is 209dec and 253dec is ý, 165dec is ¥. Again, not event relatives to what I need.

So... help me please! :(

Comment: Can you look at your file at hex editor or something that displays raw bytes? I suspect that 253 is not a byte you have in a file (because you're reading the stream as UTF-8)

Comment: Yes probably... that's my problem actually :/

Comment: As you suggested me, I looked with a hex editor, The character I have in the file has coding 209.

Comment: Note that there is no such thing as "ASCII code 165". ASCII only defines codes 0-127; codes 128-255 were only defined in encodings which extend ASCII (like CP1252, ISO 8859-1), and thus their meaning is different depending on which encoding you use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you sure that your source file you are reading is UTF-8 encoded?  In UTF-8 encoding, all values greater than 127 are reserved for a multi-byte sequence, and they are never seen standing on their own.

My guess is that the file you are reading is encoded using "code page 237" which is the original IBM PC character set.  In that character set, the Ñ is represented by the decimal 165.

Many modern systems use ISO-8859-1, which happen to be equivalent to the first 256 characters of the Unicode character set.  In those, the Ñ character is a decimal 209.  In a comment, the author clarified that a 209 is actually in the file.

If the file was really UTF-8 encoded, then the Ñ would be represented as a two-byte sequence, and would be neither the value 165 nor the value 209.

Based on the above assumption that the file is ISO-8859-1 encoded, you should be able to solve the situation by using:

```
InputStreamReader reader1 = new InputStreamReader(is, "ISO-8859-1");
```

This will translate to the Unicode characters, and you should then find the character Ñ represented by decimal 209.

Comment: Uhm I work on Android and I get an unsupported encoding exception. Where do I find all the possible encodings?

Comment: @BeppiMenozzi the answer's author though that your file contains byte 253, hence his opinion that it could be some obscure IBM PC codepage. Now we know that it's 209, hence `"ISO-8859-1"` is the correct argument (and I would expect it to be supported everywhere).

Comment: Thanks Anton, it seems to work, finally. So, should I use the same codepage also when dealing with other characters, like û or Ü?

Comment: @BeppiMenozzi Any character data transcoded to octets will be encoded in one of a [few dozen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html) encodings. If you have a "plain text" file but you don't know the encoding, you have bugs. It is better to mandate an encoding (typically UTF-8) or use a self-describing data format (e.g. JSON, XML, etc...)